# git repositories. unable to find. error

Tags: git

A few minutes ago, I commited some files and then pushed them to my github.com repository.

Then, I ran

```
git pull origin
```

on the production environment, and I got the following error:

```
error: unable to find 2fcd18343b3817d1ed79a72c0c878811ad27e834
fatal: object 2fcd18343b3817d1ed79a72c0c878811ad27e834 not found
```

What can I do to solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be that you need to specify the branch you want to pull from. For example:

```
git pull origin master
```

Also pull up a git log and see if that id appears.

Also, check to make sure you didn't change the directory you're in (i.e. make sure you're in the same folder you committed from).